# Here maps geocode wrong postal codes for Israel

Tags: here-api

I've just started checking the Here Geocode API and it looks really nice, although I experience an issue with postal codes for Israel: instead of 7-digits codes, it returns only 5 digits.

Tried it via REST:

> [https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&app_code=YOUR_APP_CODE&searchtext=הרצל+50+חיפה](https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&app_code=YOUR_APP_CODE&searchtext=%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%9C+50+%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%94)

returns postal code 33211
[image]

while the actual postal code, according to Israel Post [website](https://mypost.israelpost.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93/) is 3321103
[image]

Is this the API problem or do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HERE Map currently supports postal codes for Israel is 5 digits.
So the response postal code of geocoder API for Israel will be return only 5 digits.

Comment: Is support for 7-digit postal codes planned? If so, is there a timeline?