# Israel 5 digit postal codes rather than 7

Tags: here-api

Similar to [Here maps geocode wrong postal codes for Israel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54099143/here-maps-geocode-wrong-postal-codes-for-israel).

[image: Accuracy Claim]

7 digits is claimed on https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/coverage-geocoder.html but only 5 digits are returned.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_codes_in_Israel claims 5 digit postal codes where phased out in 2013.  So package carriers require 7 digit postal codes.

Can we expect HERE.com geocode offering to update to 7 digit postal codes in the near future?  If not, the dev guide expectation should be updated to match reality.

Comment: Bump for attention

Comment: @here-developer-support hello?

Answer (score 0):

According to HERE customer support they only support 5 digits

[Here maps geocode wrong postal codes for Israel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54099143/here-maps-geocode-wrong-postal-codes-for-israel?rq=1)

You can use [Google Geocoding APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview)

I picked a [random point in Israel](https://www.google.co.il/maps/place/%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%95%D7%94+%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%AA+-+%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%97+%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%97%D7%9D+-+Shalva+dromit%E2%80%AD/@30.9876647,34.8774739,15z/data=!4m16!1m7!3m6!1s0x1500492432a7c98b:0x6a6b422013352cba!2sIsrael!3b1!8m2!3d31.046051!4d34.851612!3m7!1s0x15023fd22ddca38b:0x880c454a6aa1ffdd!5m2!4m1!1i2!8m2!3d30.9858946!4d34.9230718), and shows the postal code in 7 digits, as desired:

*כניסה מרחוב בקצה, Nahal Avnon St 14, Yeruham, 8051869, Israel*

Comment: Or you could even use a no token related webservice e.g. https://geocode.xyz/your_address?geoit=xml